# Multinomial logit model in cross sectional time series

Tags: time-series, multinomial-distribution, cross-section

I'm working with a cross sectional time series database where my dependent variable is a set of unordered categories (hence multinomial logit).

It's highly likely my errors will be correlated over time within units and will exhibit contemporaneous correlation across units. If my DV were approximately normal I would be using panel corrected standard errors with an ar(1) lag structure.

I've seen a few packages in R and STATA which allow you to model cross sectional time series data with an unordered categorical DV and clustered standard errors, but nothing that will allow me to deal with both types of error correlation. Any suggestions?